# If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_{n}(k) = \infty$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{n}(k) = \infty$.

Tags: calculus, functions, convergence-divergence, summation

Suppose $\{f_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be functions such that $f_{n} : \Bbb{N} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^{+}$ for each $n$.

I was trying to prove -

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_{n}(k) = \infty$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{n}(k) = \infty$.

I can see that both the double summation series are  equal by expanding the double summation.But I am trying to prove it ? any other thoughts?

Hm, as the order of summation are changed, is Uniform convergence likely to play any role here?

Comment: Values in $\mathbb R^+$, yes.  You should be able to prove it.

Comment: thank u for the hint!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With nonnegative summands we have regardless of convergence of the inner sum to a finite value or $\infty$,

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_{nk} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^N f_{nk}$$ and by the MCT

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_{nk} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{nk}$$

Comment: By applying Monotone Convergence Theorem, it involves integrals and limit exchange right? here there are two summations?

Comment: Alos, how do we know that its a monotone sequence? in order to apply monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: @BAYMAX:  There is a very general way by connecting sums to integrals with counting measure but it is not necessary.  There is a monotone convergence theorem just for switching limits with sums.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^Nf_{nk}$ is an increasing sequence with respect to $N$ because each term you add is nonnegative.

Comment: great!! that clears! thank u!

Comment: I'm going to post a link from this site proving the MCT for series.  You will see that it generalizes when things converge (diverge) to $+\infty$.

Comment: thank u for the reference, will help much :)

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2616956/148510) is the proof.  Notice that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^N f_{nk} = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty S_{Nk} = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \lim_{N \to \infty} S_{Nk}$ since the partial sums $S_{Nk}$ are monotone increasing for each $k$.

Comment: Much clearer, nice!!

Comment: The key thing here is the first result -- finite sum of limits equals limit of finite sum -- when everything is nonnegative even if one of the limits is $+\infty$.