# When does this sum Convergence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $0 \leq a_n$ and $\sum_n a_n = 1$ . We also know that $a_n $ is non-zero for infinitely many n . For each $j \in \mathbb{N}$ we have non-negative sequence $(b_{j,n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $b_{j,n} \in [0,1] $ and  $b_{j,n} \uparrow a_j $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ .

Then prove that $\text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n jb_{j,n} = \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}ja_j$ ( possibly both are infinite )

Note : This result was used in probability class without proof , while computing expectations of discrete rv's

Comment: [Monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_series)

Comment: I am aware of this theorem . But , I want a real - analytic rigorous proof of the question . It seems quite nontrivial , and I am skeptical as to why it should hold true . Why are we able to to push limit inside the sum and consider individual termwise limit of the sum ?

Comment: Using Beppo Levi's theorem on the page where the measured space is $\mathbb{N}$ and the measure is the counting measure should give you more insight about the problem. If you feel it is not enough, just rewrite the proof of that theorem in your context.

Comment: Here is a very easy elementary [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2616966/148510) of the monotone convergence theorem for series.  It is "rigorous" and specialized for infinite series. This does not appeal to more complicated general proofs that view series as a special case of integrals with respect to a counting measure.

Comment: @nicomezi unfortunately , I do not know anything about measurability .

Comment: @RRL thanks for solving the problem :)